# ModuleNotFoundError on a file in a (working) package when trying to import a class on another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Abridged:

When importing a class (in the example below, `c2`) from another package (`folder1`), where the imported class (`c2`) imports a class (`c1`) from the same package (`folder1`), the program (`file2`) raises a `ModuleNotFoundError` on the import of `c1` on `c2`, even when the import already worked in the package.

Extended:

The example have the following file structure

```
project/
├── folder1/
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── file1.py
│   └── file2.py
└── folder2/
    └── file3.py
```

where the files in `folder1` contain the following classes.

`__init__.py` is left empty.

(Notice that there's no import error on `file2.py`)

```
# file1.py

class c1:
    def __init__(self, attr: int = 0):
        self.attr = attr
```

```
# file2.py

from file1 import c1

class c2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr = [c1() for _ in range(10)]
```

the file in `folder2` imports the class `c2`

```
# file3.py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')  # to recognize folder1 as a package

from folder1.file2 import c2
```

but when I try to run `file3.py` the import of `c1`  made in `file2.py` raises ModuleNotFoundError

```
$ python3 file3.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/folder2/file3.py", line 4, in <module>
    from folder1.file2 import c2
  File "/home/user/project/folder2/../folder1/file2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from file1 import c1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file1'
```

Notice that i CAN import `c1` on `file3.py` with the analogous import `from folder1.file1 import c1` but can't make it work with `c2`.

(Of course, this is an abstraction of the actual classes where i found this problem, the actual folder layout is important, but the problem is the same.)

How can I import `c2` on `folder2/file3.py`?

My attempts were trying to import `c1` before `c2` on `file3`, also tried to import   `c1` (and/or `c2`) in `folder1/__init__.py` but didn't work, also tried to make `folder2/` a package and make the import in its `__init__.py` but didn't work. Of course i (probably) could simply concatenate `file1` and `file2`  or try to create a package for `file1` but i believe I'm doing something wrong on the imports and there must a simple way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the same correct full path to `file1.py` in `file2.py`:

```
    from folder1.file1 import c1
```

When `file2.py` trying to import `file1.py`, it trying to import from `('../')` where no `file1.py`, only `/folder1` and `/folder2`.

And you can delete `__init__.py` if you are using python 3.3+.